# java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception Android Studio

Tags: java, android

hello I hope you help me, I have an activity with Android Expandable News, it was working fine but yesterday I realized that I was not showing the detail of the news, and I get this error:

java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception

the code is the following:

the error is in this line:

captionTxt.setText(mInfo.getDetalle());

```
@Layout(R.layout.feed_item)
public class InfoView {

    @ParentPosition
    private int mParentPosition;

    @ChildPosition
    private int mChildPosition;


    @View(R.id.captionTxt)
    private TextView captionTxt;


    private Preguntas mInfo;
    private Context mContext;

    public InfoView(Context context, Preguntas info) {
        mContext = context;
        mInfo = info;
    }

    @Resolve
    private void onResolved() {

        captionTxt.setText(mInfo.getDetalle());

    }
}
```

I hope someone can guide me

Answer (score 0):

InvocationTargetException occurs if you are trying to find the textview with the given ID which does not exist. 
Please verify if you get the TextView object returned by below code

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.captionTxt);
```

Verify in your  layout file, the text view ID should exactly match with the cases.